# PHP How to hit a url and download its xml

Tags: php, xml, json

I am trying to send this query:

```
http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PRK&maxRows=10&username=demo&country=US&style=full&adminCode1=AK
```

To a web service and pull down and parse a bunch of fields there, namely these:

```
// 1) totalResultsCount
// 2) name
// 3) lat
// 4) lng
// 5) countryCode
// 6) countryName
// 7) adminName1 - gives full state name
// 8) adminName2 - owner of the park.
```

I am doing this:

```
$query_string = "http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PRK&maxRows=10&username=demo&country=US&style=full&adminCode1=AK";
```

Could someone please provide the right code to loop through the results and get values?

Comment: Can you post an example of the "weird" results you get?

Comment: But that URL returns XML, not JSON!

Comment: Updated my question.  Sorry about the JSON/XML thing.  The result is in XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the response is XML, you can use [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
$url = "http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PRK&maxRows=10&username=demo&country=US&style=full&adminCode1=AK";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);

echo "totalResultsCount: " . $xml->totalResultsCount . "<br />";

foreach($xml->geoname as $geoname) {
    echo $geoname->toponymName . "<br />";
    echo $geoname->lat . "<br />";
    echo $geoname->countryCode . "<br />";
    echo $geoname->countryName . "<br />";
    echo $geoname->adminName1 . "<br />";
    echo $geoname->adminName2 . "<br />";
}
```

Which will displays the results as follows:

```
totalResultsCount: 225
Glacier Bay National Park and Preserve
58.50056
US
United States
Alaska
US.AK.232

...
```

Comment: SimpleXml can load URIs. You dont need `file_get_contents`

Comment: I overlooked that. Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, looks like that web service is returning XML rather than JSON.  You can use [SimpleXML](http://us.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) to parse that out.

Secondly, you may want to check out [curl](http://us.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)

**An Example:**

```
$ch = curl_init("http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PRK&maxRows=10&username=demo&country=US&style=full&adminCode1=AK");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$content = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: If the OP wants to parse it, there is no need for cURL at all because SimpleXml can load remote URIs.

Comment: Good call.  worth noting that his original question was quite different (it was about JSON).  My initial point was a side note about his specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

fopen will give you a resource, no the file.  Since you're doing a json decode, you'll want to just the whole thing as a string.  Easiest way to do this is file_get_contents.

```
$query = 'http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PRK&maxRows=10&username=demo&country=US&style=full&adminCode1=AK';
$response = file_get_contents($query);
// You really should do error handling on the response here.
$decoded = json_decode($response, true);
echo '<p>Decoded: '.$decoded['lat'].'</p>';
```

Comment: Although... it would appear that the response data from your API is returning XML... so the above code won't work as is.

Comment: Yes it is actually XML.  I made an oversight.