# How to hit a url and download its xml using php

Tags: php, xml, json, curl

I tried everything to get the xml from the url, even smottt idea from [PHP How to hit a url and download its xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026826/php-how-to-hit-a-url-and-download-its-xml) , but didnt work for me.

my scenario;

URL that generates Dollar Exchange Rates:

[nrb.org.np/exportForexXML.php?YY=2015&MM=03&DD=01&YY1=2015&MM1=03&DD1=01](http://nrb.org.np/exportForexXML.php?YY=2015&MM=03&DD=01&YY1=2015&MM1=03&DD1=01)

Here: **YY MM DD** are the starting date and **YY1 MM1 DD1** are the ending date of report. I believe , it generates an xml in unix time of Kathmandu, Asia. Everytime and second seperate xml file name.

Searched internet but nothing,

I want to display the result of xml in a page using php either by downloading the xml from the given url to my localhost folder or directly from web.

please help.

Thanks in Advance

Edited: Code I am using is

```
$url = "nrb.org.np/exportForexXML.php?YY=2015&MM=03&DD=01&YY1=2015&MM1=03&DD1=01";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);

foreach($xml->CurrencyConversionResponse as $CurrencyConversionResponse) {
    echo $CurrencyConversionResponse->BaseCurrency . "<br />";
    echo $CurrencyConversionResponse->TargetCurrency . "<br />";
    echo $CurrencyConversionResponse->ConversionTime . "<br />";
    echo $CurrencyConversionResponse->ConversionRate . "<br />";

}
```

And the error message is

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "nrb.org.np/exportForexXML.php?YY=2015&MM=03&DD=01&YY1=2015&MM1=03&DD1=01" in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml.php on line 4

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\xml.php(4): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('nrb.org.np/expo...', 0, true) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml.php on line 4
```

Comment: Can we see the code that you tried and any error(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `http://` to the URL

```
$url = "http://nrb.org.np/exportForexXML.php?YY=2015&MM=03&DD=01&YY1=2015&MM1=03&DD1=01";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);

foreach($xml->CurrencyConversionResponse as $CurrencyConversionResponse) {
    echo $CurrencyConversionResponse->BaseCurrency . "<br />";
    echo $CurrencyConversionResponse->TargetCurrency . "<br />";
    echo $CurrencyConversionResponse->ConversionTime . "<br />";
    echo $CurrencyConversionResponse->ConversionRate . "<br />";
}
```