# Scrape the data of table from remote website and insert in mySQL

Tags: web-scraping, preg-match, simple-html-dom

I have tried `simplehtmldom` to get the contents or data from a website and update to my MySQL. But I couldn't as the whole website is designed on table without class or div. The data is of exchange rates from a website. 
The website exports exchange rates value by methods,

```
I)  XML
II) Excel
```

the xml is solved here but it only shows selling rates
[How to hit a url and download its xml using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802538/how-to-hit-a-url-and-download-its-xml-using-php)

Second method is , it Creates an Excel File where there are all the data

buying and selling
here is the link: 
http://nrb.org.np/detailexchrate.php?YY=&&MM=&&DD=&&YY1=&&MM1=&&DD1=

I want to get the values by order and insert in data base or variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are good in xpath, you just scrape html, select/cut off that table, turn it into DOM and traverse it with xpath (without simplehtmldom, see [here](http://scraping.pro/using-domxpath-for-parsing-page-content-in-php/) how):

```
// inside a loop with i
...xpath->query('//tbody/tr[1]/td[i]'); // output -> USD 
...xpath->query('//tbody/tr[2]/td[i]'); // output -> 60
```

Comment: hi Igor Savinkin.. I did gave a try from ur suggest and the links you provided.. but failed.. i copied the xpath of the table where currency is, and run the query.. but of no use.. can you please help a bit further here

Comment: @AarveeThapa, ok, just expose your code and describe your attempts.